# Why are votes counted so quickly on election day, then slow down afterwards?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

In following the ongoing US election, I notice that most states seem to count votes much faster on day 1. For example on election night, Pennsylvannia counted ~80% of its total votes, but it's been several days since and they still haven't counted the remaining 20%.

Why is the pace of vote counting so fast on the first day? Why does it slow down afterwards?

Comment: The Pennsylvania legislature forbade its election officials from processing mail-in ballots before polls closed on Election Day. Those ballots piled up, flattened and folded, in some cases for weeks.